# Why i have no internet connectivity from inside Ubuntu VM?

Tags: ubuntu, microk8s

The ubuntu local VM was launched using "multipass" on a MacOS machine.
Once in the VM, i used the microk8s command to download and install the "snap" app (this was part of a MS tutorial), but errors happened.

This is the code i tried to run:

```
ubuntu@microk8s-vm2:~$ sudo snap install microk8s --classic
        error: unable to contact snap store
```

Apparently a networking error ..

A detailed error from syslogs shows the following:

```
Aug 23 13:26:42 microk8s-vm2 snapd[698]: taskrunner.go:271: [change 4 "Request device serial" task] failed: 
cannot retrieve request-id for making a request for a serial: 
Post https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/auth/request-id: net/http: 
request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Also note that curl command returns the following:

```
curl -v  https://api.snapcraft.io
*   Trying 185.125.188.55:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
...
```

[it gets stuck here]

curl test:

```
ubuntu@microk8s-vm2:/var/log$ curl google.com
curl: (28) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have connectivity from that VM box.
I advice you to check the network settings of the Ubuntu vm you are typing from.